# Retrieving the value of a dynamically created dropdown inside datatable

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, datatables

I have created 2 textboxes, 2 dropdowns inside a datatable dynamically. I have a button 'Add'. When it is clicked, this datatable with dynamic control is created. The first dropdown's value is filled from an external control. The first dropdown contains the projectid and projectname. The second dropdwon should contain the member names those who are associated with the selected project.

The thing is I've unique id for both the dropdowns. Like, if two rows are added, the first dropdown project will have the id "Project_0", second project dropdown will have "Project_1", similarly, first member dropdown will have the id "Who_0", second will have "Who_2". This is how it happens.

My requirement is, when the first project dropdown is selected with a project, the first member dropdown should have the member names who are associated with that project.

My problem is, I don't know how to proceed, ie how to retrieve the value from the first project dropdown, send it to the db and fetch the value.

This is how I've tried:

```
$("#CustomerID").off("click").on("click",function(){
                    if($(this).val()=="0"){
                        projectid = [];     
                    }
                    else{
                        $.ajax({
                            method: "GET",
                            url: "../api/momapi.php?action=getprojectsbycustomerid",
                            data: {"CustomerID":$(this).val()},
                            success: function(data) {
                                console.log(data);
                                projectid = $.parseJSON(data);
                            },
                            error:function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                                alert( errorThrown );
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
MomActivity = $("#MomActivity").DataTable({
            "sDom": "t",
            "ajax":{
                "url": "../api/momapi.php?action=getmombyid",
                "type": "GET",
                "data": {"MomID": <?php echo $_GET["MomID"]; ?>}    
            },
            "destroy": true,
            "ordering": false,
            "columns": [
                        {
                            "title": "Project", "data": "projectid", "render": function(data, type, row){
                                return '<select class="form-control selectProjectID" id="Project_'+a+'" name="ProjectID[]" valueid='+ data +'></select>';
                            }   
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "What", "data": "what", "render": function(data, type, row){
                                return  '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="What[]" value="'+ data +'">';            
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Who", "data": "who", "render": function(data, type, row){
                                return  '<select class="form-control selectWho" name="Who[]" id="Who_'+c+'" value="'+ data +'">';           
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "When", "data": "when", "render": function(data, type, row){
                                return  '<input type="text" class="form-control whendate" name="When[]" value="'+ moment(data).format("DD-MM-YYYY") +'">';          
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "...", "render": function(data, type, row){
                                return '<input type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm remove" value="Remove" name="remove" id="remove">';          
                            }
                        }

            ],
            "drawCallback": function(settings){
                $(".selectProjectID").each(function(){
                        if($(this).find("option").length == 0){
                            $(this).fillSelect(projectid,"projectid","projectname",0,1).val($(this).attr("valueid"));
                        }                   
                })
                $(".selectWho").each(function(){
                        if($(this).find("option").length == 0){
                            $(this).fillSelect(momuserid, "userid", "username", 0,1).val($(this).attr("valueid"));
                        }
                });
            },
            "rowCallback": function( row, data, index ) {
                $('td > input.remove', row).off("click").on("click",function(){
                    MomActivity.row($(this).parents('tr')).remove().draw();
                });
                $('td > input.whendate', row).datetimepicker({ format: "DD-MM-YYYY" });
            },
            "fnCreatedRow": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull){
                a = a + 1;
                c = c + 1;
            }           
        });  

if($("#CustomerID").val()=="0"){
                MyNotif.Show("Select customer","warning");
            }
            else{
                var selectedProjectID =$("#MomActivity").find('tr:last-child').find('.selectProjectID').val();
                if(typeof selectedProjectID == 'undefined')
                {
                    selectedProjectID = "";
                    MomActivity.row.add({"projectid":selectedProjectID,"what":"","who":"","when":""}).draw();   
                }
                else if(selectedProjectID == "")
                {
                    MyNotif.Show("Select project","warning");
                }
                else{
                    alert(selectedProjectID);
                    MomActivity.row.add({"projectid":selectedProjectID,"what":"","who":"","when":""}).draw();
                }    
            }
```

Ultimately, I've to retrieve the value from .selectProjectID, send it to DB. How can I do that?

Comment: You know what would really help? A sample JSFiddle with the basic structure. Create a JSON object to populate your table. Then we might be able to help you.

Comment: I'm not able to create a JSFiddle. I don't know what's wrong..